# What type of delimiter should i use in Pig Latin to process apache log?

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

If this is how my Apache log looks, what delimiter should I use in PigLatin to split the data.

```
[Mon Jul 02 10:04:18 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /home/ec2-  user/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx, referer: http://xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/
```

I tried PigStorage(',') to split the referer and the other string. But how can I split

```
[Mon Jul 02 10:04:18 2012] [error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /home/ec2-user/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx
```

If I use space as the delimiter Mon Jul 02 10:04:18 2012 gets split into multiple string.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Log Loaders, as part of [Piggybank](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank)?

- http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.com/2011/06/analyzing-apache-logs-with-pig.html
- http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/06/analyzing-apache-logs-with-pig/

Answer (score 0):

That's what I use:

```
REGISTER  /usr/local/pig-0.10.0/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar;        
A = load '*.log'
        USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader(
              '(DATETIMEREX) (ERROREX) (CLIENTEX) (.*)')
        AS ( 
                 dateTime : chararray, 
                 error    : chararray,
                 client   : chararray, 
                 line     : chararray );
```

Susbtitute the DATETIMEX, ERROREX, CLIENTEX with the appropriate regular expressions.